# Another Div Alignment issue

Tags: css, html, css-float, alignment, floating

I just posted on here with a problem that I am having with div alignment. My original question was answered but now I am having yet another issue. Link to what I am trying to do: [Click here for the images](http://testnow.us/divimages) (Nothing harmful by clicking on link) and by the way, this is NOT for homework. The top image (Something I created in Fireworks) on the link is the layout I was first trying to do (I got that issue resolved), but now I am trying to add a sitename div and as you see in the second picture, it is creating issues with the right div.

I am really off my game yesterday and today and making these simple stupid mistakes. I just need another pair of eyes to see what my issues are. 
Thanks.

CSS:

```
#header {
width:750px;
height:341px;
margin-left:25px;
display:block;
}
#tableleft {
float: left;
width: 128px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top:10px;
}
#Sitename {
text-align: center;
white-space: normal;
display: table;
float: left;
width: 400px;
height:40px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:25px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;

}
#tablecenter {
margin-left:20px;
float: left;
width: 410px;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-top:30px;
}
#tableright {
float: right;
width: 128px;
margin-left: 20x;
margin-right:10px;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="tableleft">
    <div align="center">
      <p><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" width="118" height="87" /></p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" width="118" height="87" /></p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" width="118" height="87" /></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Sitename">Content for  id "Sitename" Goes Here</div>

  <div id="tablecenter">
    <h1><img src="images/LgWhitepic.jpg" width="410" height="242" /></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="tableright">
    <p align="center"><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" alt="" width="118" height="87"  /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center"><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" alt="" width="118" height="87" /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center"><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" alt="" width="118" height="87" /></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Paragraphs are not suitable containers for images. You should be using a styled unordered list.

Comment: the paragraph tags were added to created extra space. these are not the issue though because I had then in before I added the Sitename div. Whatever I did was when adding that last div but I have been staring at this for far to long and cannot figure out what happened at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest `<div id="Sitename">Content for  id "Sitename" Goes Here</div>` within `<div id="tablecenter">` but remove the `float: left;` and let it `display: block;`

Comment: OMG I am such an idiot. Thank you maceyj2. that worked perfect. If I would just stop and take a break I would notice things like this!

Comment: i did leave the float left in though and it works that way too.

Comment: happy to help! but you should remove the float if its not needed - optimize your CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Because `<div id="tableright">` is AFTER `<div id="tablecenter">` it starts from the same position from top. Like waterfall.
Switch them.